Net does not show any connection in PCB
In the following schematic I have a net called "IR_VCC_MCU", which is connected to another schematic sheet as you can see in the second schematic:

But the issue is when I update the schematic, I see this net name on the MCU pin as follows, but there is no line indicating this pin can be routed to Q2, and in fact I can not do the routing!

Would you please let me know how can fix this?

i need to connect these two pins in a higher level in my main schematic, as follows:

I have forgot to this to connect these two schematic together.

Yes it does depend if your schematics use hirearchial representation. It sound like you do so you will need to have a higher level header file that only contains your hirearchial interconnections from your lower levels etc. However I'm surprised you did not get an error when you compiled your project ? Did you get an error or warning or something at all ??

@citizen suprisngly not, I did not get any error.

In your schematic project, have you selected your Net Identifier Scope ? Go check under Project -> Project Options -> Options -> Net Identifier Scope and make sure you choose Hierarchial or Strict Hierarchial (or whatever you want your net scope to be on your schematics).
